# IntelliJ - push a branch other than the current one

Tags: git, intellij-idea, git-push

From the command line I can do

```
$ git push origin branchB
```

even when I am currently on `branchA`. Is there an equivalent command in IntelliJ IDEA? As far as I can tell, I can only push the current branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDEA does not allow pushing non-current branch at the moment. Here is the request to add this ability, please vote:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-164356

Answer (score -1):

You can use the terminal within Intellij. If you have git-bash installed, you can tell Intellij that you want your terminal to be the git-cmd.exe (for Windows).

Settings -> Tools -> Terminal -> Shell Path

Not sure if this works on Linux/Mac OS X

When you open the terminal, you can run the command you posted in the question

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer my question. Using the terminal in IntelliJ is not fundamentally different from starting cmd, bash, etc. and not what I am looking for.

Comment: Sure. I thought it was more helpful then telling you that you cannot. I thought perhaps you wanted to remain working within the Intellij window, rather than switching applications.

Comment: Yes, I want to stay in the IntelliJ window. I also don't want to type the command. I am asking about a keyboard shortcut or option in the usual Push window when you press Ctrl-Shift-K.